# Is there a way to connect to MySQL 8 from rubymotion?

Tags: mysql, rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

is there a workaround that allows me to connect and query MySQL 8 database from within my rubymotion (RedPotion) Projet, instead of defining and statically compiling my schema in rubymotion??

Below is my development environment.
Ruby version 2.5.8
RubyMotion 7.4
ProMotion 2.8.2
cocoapods 1.8.0
redpotion 1.7.1